# How to create filters in Spring boot based on a List

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have to created filters data in spring boot. From frontEnd, I am sending a list containing the selected id of each category.I need to return items based on this list. I can do it this way

Service:

```
    public List<ProductModel> getProductFilter(Integer[] categories) {
        int size = categories.length;

        if(size == 1){
            return productRepository.getProductFilteredByOneCategory(Long.valueOf(categories[0]));
        }else {
            return productRepository.getProductFilteredByTwoCategory(Long.valueOf(categories[0]),Long.valueOf(categories[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM ProductModel c WHERE c.categoryModel.id = :Category_id")
List<ProductModel> getProductFilteredByOneCategory(Long Category_id);

@Query("SELECT c FROM ProductModel c WHERE c.categoryModel.id = :Category_idOne OR c.categoryModel.id = :Category_idTwo")
List<ProductModel> getProductFilteredByTwoCategory(Long Category_idOne, Long Category_idTwo);
```

But if there are 50 of these categories, it is useless. Can anyone tell me how to make it better? There is some way to generate a query from a list?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in` instead of using multiple `or` operations as follows. It select all productModels match any categoryModel id in List.

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM ProductModel c WHERE c.categoryModel.id in category_ids")
List<ProductModel> getProductFilteredByCategoryIds(List<Long> Category_ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

As @YJR said, `IN` clause is the solution, but you should also consider declaring [query method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details) as shown below, which doesn't require writing JPQL.

```java
public List<ProductModel> findByCategoryModel_IdIn(List<Long> categoryIds);
```